# UIStackView removeFromSuperView layout changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uistackview

I have a horizontal stack view and I have three `UIViews` in it. Each time on `viewDidAppear` I want to add center subview and remove the same subview depending on some conditions.

In storyboard; I have added Stack View to `ALIGNMENT: FILL`; `DISTRIBUTION: FILL EQUALLY`; and `SPACING: 0`.
But Each time I am trying to remove the UIView; it doesnt space out the remaining views equally.

I have even tried to change distribution to equal spacing or FILL; it is the same result. Any help is appreciated.

Following is the code for removing and adding a `UIView`:

```
self.secondView = self.stackView.arrangedSubviews[1];
[self.stackView removeArrangedSubview:self.secondView];
[self.secondView removeFromSuperview];
[self.stackView layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: Surely it would be simpler to just update the content of the existing view?

Comment: can you help me in explaining that statement more ? I thought stackview would be like linear layout in android but it is not working as expected.

Comment: Well, say `self.secondview` was a label,  it is much simpler to update that label's `text` property than to remote it and add a whole new label.  Rather than adding a whole new subview, can you just update the content of the existing subview?  If you are going to add a new subview you need to ensure that any required constraints and layout properties such as hugging priorities are created so that things are laid out as you need it

Comment: true but I am trying to remove the self.secondView first. If I am removing the view from the stack of views as above; the other two views dont get same width and height.